# Predicate individual-level

Tags: predicate

I’ve come across one post on a website. See below;

I wish my father had been rich.
(Father is already dead and was poor)

I am trying to understand more about predicate individual-level and do need more input.

Can anyone tell me how did that sentence evoke lifetime effect?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *How did that sentence evoke lifetime effect?*, but what I *can* say is that ***had been*** in your example doesn't *necessarily* imply your father is dead - just that he definitely wasn't rich at some point in the past. As opposed to subjunctive/irrealis *I wish he **were** rich*, which simply implies that *at time of speaking,* he isn't.

Comment: Thanks! I thought of the same too. It was not my answer, it was theirs - ‘father is dead and was poor’. I just wonder how did it evoke the lifetime effect. Again, appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

Considering you were able to transform the "see below" mishmash into the grammatically correct interpretation which you posited, you appear to be in very little need of help, if you ever were. Does that help?

Comment: I don’t follow you. You mean I shall be in very little need of help if I be able to interpret the meaning of that sentence?

Comment: Don't yet fathom why  one would down or up vote what one does not understand.  Being as yet unable to edit your question, seemed you made sense of the poorly written example you gave. Your question was a bit hard to decipher, however. No offense intended. I should have ignored the question.

Comment: In other words, I was down voted for a compliment.